# In Python, how do I search an html webpage for a set of strings in text file?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, text-files

I'm trying to figure out a way to search an html webpage for a number of strings that I have written in a text file, each on its own line. The code I have so far is this:

```
def mangasearch():
    r = requests.get("https://www.mangaupdates.com/releases.html")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
    if soup.find(text=re.compile(line)):
        print("New chapter found!")
        print("")
    else:
        print("No new chapters")
        print("")


def textsearch():
    global line
    with open("manga.txt") as file:
        for line in file:
            print(line)
            mangasearch()
```

It's supposed to read manga.txt and search the webpage for each string separately, but it always returns "no new chapters". If I replace `if soup.find(text=re.compile(line)):` with `if soup.find(text=re.compile("An actual string")):` it works correctly, but for some reason it doesn't want to use the `line` variable. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I suspect your `line` variable has a trailing newline, try `line.strip()`, or at least less zealously `line.rstrip('\n\r')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to search with a string that contains some special character, like ' ', and '\n'.

Note that str.strip() removes ' ' and other whitespace characters as well (e.g. tabs and newlines), so, update the following line:

```
if soup.find(text=re.compile(line.strip())):
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def textsearch():
  #manga_file = open("managa.txt").readlines()
  ##assuming your text file has 3 titles
  manga_file = ["Karakuri Circus","Sun-ken Rock","Shaman King Flowers"]

  manga_html = "https://www.mangaupdates.com/releases.html"

  manga_page = urllib2.urlopen(manga_html)

  found = 0

  soup = BeautifulSoup(manga_page)
  ##use BeautifulSoup to parse the section of interest out
  ##use 'inspect element' in Chrome or Firefox to find the interesting table
  ##in this case the data you are targeting is in a <div class="alt"> element
  chapters = soup.findAll("div", attrs={"class":"alt"})
  ##chapters now contains all of the sections under the dates on the page
  ##so we iterate through each date to get all of the titles in each
  ##<tr> element of each table

  for dated_section in chapters:
      rows = dated_section.findAll("tr")
      for r in rows:
          title = r.td.text
          #print title
          #url = r.td.a.href
          if title in manga_file:
              found +=1 
              print "New Chapter Found!"
              print r
  if found >0:
      print "Found a total of %d title"%found
  else:
      print "No chapters found"
```

above is not meant to be optimized but it does a good job of showing how BeautifulSoup can be used to parse the specific elements that you are looking for.  In this case I used Chrome, right-clicked on the table that contains the titles to "inspect-element' and looked for the element that contains them to direct BeautifulSoup's attention directly to there.  The rest is explained in code.  I don't know what your managa.txt file looks like so I just created a list of 3 titles to search for as an example.